# Display Decimals & Currency Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, decimal, currency

I have a local environmental variable in my show.html.erb `@experiment.baseline_conversion_60`

The baseline_conversion_60 is stored as a decimal in my database. When I display this variable in my show it always displays as a whole number. How can I show it as a decimal?

I also have another variable that is stored as a decimal, but I would like to display as currency. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Looks like I can use round()